# Unable to find an entry point named 'OpsConGetMaxOpenCursorInfo' in DLL 'OraOps12.dll'

Tags: c#

I am creating a SOAP service using C#.Net. I have downloaded ODAC 12 Dlls and included in my  solution so that on target machine, I don't need to install Oracle Client. The solution was working fine.

Now, i created a new service in VS 2015 and target framework is 4.5.2. When i tried to connect database below exception is thrown;

Unable to find an entry point named 'OpsConGetMaxOpenCursorInfo' in DLL 'OraOps12.dll'.

Anyone has any idea why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

It has been resolved, because i was creating web service. I added DLLs in solution for future reference but it will not auto copied to BIN folder. I need to copy them manually and then issue was resolved because process was not able to locate them.